# Numerical Analysis. Newton-Raphson formula.

Tags: numerical-methods

[image: Condition]

Attempt:

a)
$g(x) = x- f(x)/f’(x) = 
x – [(x-2)^4]/[4(x-2)^3] = 
(2-x)/4+x = (3x+2)/4$

So, $p_k = [3p_{k-1}+2] /4$

b)

> > p(1)=2.1;
> >     for j=2:5,
> >     p(j) = (3*p(j-1)+2)/4
> >     end

p =
    2.1000    2.0750    2.0563    2.0422    2.0316

So, 
p(0)=1

p(1)=2.0750

p(2)=2.0563

p(3)=2.0422

p(4)=2.0316

c) Tried this:

for i=1:4
p(i+1)-p(i)
end

ans = 
-0.0250

ans =  -0.0187

ans = 
-0.0141

ans =
 -0.0105

So,
p(1)-p(0) = -0.0250

p(2)-p(1)= -0.0187

p(3)-p(2)= -0.0141

p(4)-p(3) = -0.0105

What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $(x-2)^4=0$ has the obvious root $x=2$.

We have 
$$p_{n+1}-2=\frac{3p_n+2}{4}-2=\frac{3}{4}(p_n-2).$$
Thus
$$|p_{n+1}-2|=\frac{3}{4}|p_n-2|.$$

So the distance from  the root is multiplied by the factor $\frac{3}{4}$ for each iteration. This is *linear* convergence.

**Remark:** Note that the behaviour of the Newton Method in this case is *worse* than the behaviour of the Bisection Method.

The reason for the bad behaviour is that the derivative of our function $(x-2)^4$ is $0$ at the root.

Comment: thank you for a fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

Given the recurrence you have derived, it is apparent that

$$p_n = 2 + \left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^n (p_1 - 2)$$

so that

$$p_{n+1}-p_n = \frac{3}{4} (p_n-p_{n-1})$$

Your recurrence converges to the root $x=2$ linearly.